# How to select XML attribute value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

```
          <category field="height">
            <num>185</num>
          </category>
          <category field="weight">
            <num>90</num>
          </category>
```

I need to get value from tag `num` only from tag `category`, where attribute `field` equals `weight`.

Note: `field="height"` may be missing from XML.

Comment: do you store `XML` in the database ?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to so for every row in one query in SELECT section.

Comment: But you can't do that with `SQL` as your storing the `XML` in a column, so the `SELECT` returns the content of that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `num` elements where the parent `category`'s `field` attribute is `"weight"`:

```
ExtractValue(xml, '//category[@field="weight"]/num')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: `SELECT ExtractValue(xml, '//category/num[../@field="weight"]');`

Comment: I'm curious as to why you prefer your XPath, which is unnecessarily more verbose, over the [one I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443045/290085).

Comment: Oh, sorry, it actually was an accident.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for explaining and switching it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ExtractValue('<category field="height"><num>185</num></category><category field="weight"><num>90</num></category>', 'category/num[../@field="weight"]');
```

That is

```
SELECT ExtractValue(Column, 'category/num[../@field="weight"]');
```